# How to send a Purchase Order using Xero API

Tags: xero-api

We have successfully created Purchase Order using API. But can't seem to find a parameter to have Xero send the purchase order to contact (as their front end provides). The closest I see is SentToContact but it seems to be just a flag to change the status to sent. Anyone has any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emails can't be triggered through the API. You can use the API to create the Purchase Order, but you'll need to use the Xero interface to have Xero send the email.